# Random selection combobox delphi 7

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

I have Items listed in my combobox in delphi 7 and I'm referring to them using their respective index numbers and it's working well.
Now what I want is to add a functionality of randomizing selection whereby a user selects random and then one of the items in the combobox will be select.
I have done some research but all the results I get are not close to what I want.
P'se render me some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) function in the `Math` unit to obtain a random integer within a given range:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRandomItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := RandomRange(0, ComboBox1.Items.Count);
end;
```

Notice that `RandomRange(A, B)` yields a random integer in [A, B) ∩ ℤ = {A, A + 1, ..., B − 1}.

Don't forget to call [`Randomize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Randomize) one time before you need to use random numbers. (You can call it during application startup.)

**Update:**

If `Math.RandomRange` is not available in Delphi 7, you can use [`Random(int)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Random) instead:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRandomItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := Random(ComboBox1.Items.Count);
end;
```

`Random(B)` yields an integer in [0, B) ∩ ℤ = {0, 1, ..., B − 1}.

Comment: thanks Andreas, is this function available in Delphi 7 as well